# Prefilled information during installation process of some applications (software) in Windows

Tags: windows, email, security

I wanted to install software ("PDF-XChange") to Windows 10 Home (as my operating system).
During the installation steps of this software (in step "Registration Information"), I saw a prefilled field "username". A value used for this prefilled field was one of my email addresses.
I didn't write that email address during the installation, and I didn't register on the website of this software.

I thought that this email address was taken automatically by that software installation process somewhere from Windows parts therefore:

1. I removed this email address from "Accounts used by other apps" (under Start -> Settings -> Email & accounts).
2. I removed this email address also from Microsoft Edge (browser) from edge://settings/profiles

I don't know where else I could check if that email address is used or sign-in, ... and I want to be sure that there is no security settings that I should be aware of and potentially fix/update it.

- In other words, the fact that a software prefilled my email address during the installation process is not so important, but I am afraid if there is not any issue with my privacy or security settings in my operating system.

Do you have any idea what else I could check or update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different applications can prefill different information that they can access within your operating system, e.g. system variables or registry key values, ...

In this specific case, the information was filled from RegisteredOwner:
win + r -> regedit -> OK -> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion -> RegisteredOwner

Therefore, in my case, there is not any issue with my privacy or security settings in my operating system, just the source for that prefilled value was very hidden (at least for me).

If you like, you can change Value data for that RegisteredOwner which will be also reflected during a relevant installation process.